# php video file upload and play using videoJS

Tags: php, html, video

im trying to upload a video file into db and play it with videoJS player.
Everything ok but the video doesn't work and it shows loading icon and there it stops and the video is not played. does anyone can find out whats wrong? im using video js www.videojs.com

This is the index.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Upload System</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
</head>
<body>
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
?>

<div id='box'>
    <form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <?php
        if(isset($_FILES['video'])){



        $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
        $type = explode('.', $name);
        $type = end($type);
        $size = $_FILES['video']['size'];
        $random_name = rand();
        $tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];    

        if($type != 'mp4' && $type != 'MP4' && $type != 'avi'){
            $message = "Video Format Not Supported";
        }else{
            move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$random_name.'.'.$type);
            mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO cinema VALUES ('','$name','$random_name.$type')");
            $message = "Successfully Uploaded";
        }

        echo "$message <br/><br/>";

        }
    ?>

        Select Video: <br/>
        <input type='file' name='video' />
        <br><br>
        <input type='submit' value='Upload Video'/>
    </form>
</div>

<div id='box'>
<?php
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id, name, url FROM cinema");
    while ($run = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $video_id = $run['id'];
        $video_name = $run['name'];
        $video_url = $run['url'];
?>
    <a href="view.php?video=<?php echo $video_url; ?>">
    <div id='url'>
        <?php echo $video_name; ?>
    </div>
    </a>
<?php
    }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the view.php file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Video Upload System</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
?>

<div id='box'>

<?php
    $video = $_GET['video'];
?>
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
  <source src="<?php echo $video; ?>" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest videojs(zip) player here: http://www.videojs.com/

Extract the zip file and use the demo.html you probably need to build in autoplay = yes, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<head>

<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<body>     

 <?php
    if(isset($_FILES['video'])){



    $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
    $type = explode('.', $name);
    $type = end($type);
    $size = $_FILES['video']['size'];
    $random_name = rand();
    $tmp = $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];    

    if($type != 'mp4' && $type != 'MP4' && $type != 'avi'){
        $message = "Video Format Not Supported";
    }else{
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$random_name.'.'.$type);
        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO cinema VALUES ('','$name','$random_name.$type')");
        $message = "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    echo "$message <br/><br/>";

    }
?>     

   <div id='box'>
<form method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    Select Video: <br/>
    <input type='file' name='video' />
    <br><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Upload Video'/>
</form>

<video id="MY_VIDEO_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
 data-setup="{}">
 <source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
 <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
</body>
  </html>
```